# mongod and mongo both are not running, showing error, can anyone tell whats the problem

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try starting the mongo shell with:

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --logpath /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

Details are in the mongoDB docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x-tarball/

Comment: it did not work